# How can i pass an array of structs to a function?

Tags: c++, struct

I have an array of a struct called Pair that has many values. How can I pass this array and iterate through it to print out all the values?

```
bool reflexive(Pair* a, int sizeOfA)
struct Pair {
  int x,y;
}one[5];

int main()
{


    one[0].x = one[0].y = 1;
    one[1].x = one[1].y = 2;
    one[2].x = one[2].y = 3;
    one[3].x = one[3].y = 4;
    one[4].x = one[4].y = 5;
    reflexive(&one, 5);         // I may also need to change this line
}

bool reflexive(Pair* a, int sizeOfA){    // This is the line that i need to change
  cout << a[0].x;          // I need to iterate through array and print all values

}
```

My Question:
  How do i change my function so it will work and how do i iterate through the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you pass an array of any type. 
Even without pointer notation:

```
bool reflexive(Pair a[], int sizeOfA)   // or Pair* a
{ 
  cout << a[0].x;         
}
```

Call:

```
reflexive(one, 5);         // or &one[0], address of first element (both equivalent)
```

To iterate: (inside the funciton)

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeOfA;i++)
cout<<a[i].x;
```

Note that arrays are passed by reference.
Note also that the prototype in the first line is missing a semicolon.

Comment: Arrays are not passed by reference. They're pointers passed by value. You can pass them as a reference to a pointer if you wish, but in the example in question, they're passed by value.

Comment: I am aware of that. Just putting it simple for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change only function call:

```
reflexive(&(one[0]), 5);
```

Comment: that should be question to user1082764. The question was how to pass an array of objects to a function.

Comment: An array passed to a function will decay to a pointer to its first element so saying `&(one[0])` is redundant and kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon at the end of the first line. Also avoid using global variables unless you are absolutely sure you need it.

Change

```
reflexive(&one, 5);
```

To

```
reflexive(one, 5);
```

And use [for loop](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) inside reflexive method. Moreover, change the signature of the reflexive method to -

```
bool reflexive(Pair[]* a, int sizeOfA)
```

Comment: @user1082764 : you also would need to add a semicolon at the end of first line

Comment: this is explicit array to pointer cast, you should rather take an address of 1st array element.

Comment: The method signature should be updated too, if the user wants to iterate over it. It's better to have clean understandable code

Answer (score 0):

Jerry's solution works just fine but here is an alternative that avoids having the hardcoded 5 you are passing and/or any sizeof type expressions. This solution prevents the array decaying into just a pointer, which is how it loses the information about how big the array is. One can prevent the decay by passing the array by reference as opposed to a pointer.

If you always pass an array of size 5 you can change the reflexive function to this:

```
bool reflexive(Pair (&a)[5])
{
    for (const auto& b : a)
        cout << b.x;
    return true;
}
```

As one can see, this still retains a hardcoded 5 in the function declaration. If you always pass an array of known size, i.e. not dynamically sized at runtime, one can get rid of that using templates:

```
template<size_t size> bool reflexive(Pair (&a)[size])
{
    for (const auto& b : a)
        cout << b.x;
    return true;
}
```

Now you can call reflexive with any fixed size array like so (using your original code):

```
struct Pair {
  int x,y;
}one[5];

int main()
{
    one[0].x = one[0].y = 1;
    one[1].x = one[1].y = 2;
    one[2].x = one[2].y = 3;
    one[3].x = one[3].y = 4;
    one[4].x = one[4].y = 5;
    reflexive(one);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm suggesting this because disentangling the count of elements in the array & the array itself can easily create errors where a developer accidentally passes the wrong number of elements.